# How to get back page action in angular

Tags: angular

how to get back page action

This button

[image: 1]

I want to remove data about past pages when a user visits certain pages

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you're asking about not adding navigation changes inside browser history for certain routes.

You can do the same using `replaceUrl` parameter.

**TS**

```
this.router.navigate(['/url/page'], { replaceUrl: true })
```

**HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="'/url/page'" [replaceUrl]="true">
  Other Page
</a>
```